# Trouble with Eclipse Listener and getting the Source

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In My Eclipse Project, I have a

```
Text custom_text = new Text(....);
```

Now I add a listener -

> custom_text.addKeyListener(new
>   KeyListener(){
>
> @Override  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
>
> }
>
> @Override   public void
>   keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
>         System.err.println("event
>   "+event.getSource()));
>
> } });

Anyhow, I am not getting the source name,despite I am getting the output as Text {}.
Well I want to get the source name ie custom_text .

> How to get the output in a listener as
>   custom_text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you can not the name of the variable, holding the reference to your textfield. It is also not really of any use to know the name of the variable, since you can have many referencing variables.

With *.getSource()* you get a full reference to the widget itself, so you can deal with it in any way.

Comment: Actually I am expecting the name because of some other use. Moreover getSource() is only printing Text() as output. So I am stuck . Actually In Swing.. we get the object reference name . so I expected the same behaviour here

Comment: You will **never** get "custom_text".  That information is lost on compile.  This source is still the object reference, it just overrides toString() an outputs "Text{}".  Swing also would not print "custom_text" based on what you have written.  Or do you mean you want the **contents** of the Text widget?

Comment: Yes.. I was confused about my Objective. @above all are correct in their point...

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.widget to identify wich widget notify event.

But general approach is relaying with anonymous listener.
because it can use more readable method name which is more fit to subject of controller.

```
Text nameField, emailField = ...

nameField.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener(){
    public void handleEvent(Event e){
        handleNameEdited();   
    } 
});

emailField.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener(){
   public void handleEvent(Event e){
       handleEmailEdited();
   }
});
```